# Use Laplace's method with $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{x(3u-u^3)}du$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: asymptotics, laplace-method

Use Laplace's method with $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{x(3u-u^3)}du$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$.
I'm confused about how to taylor expand about u=1? How do I continue? Obviously first of all I have converted it to:
$$\int_{1-\epsilon}^{1+\epsilon}e^{x(3u-u^3)}du$$
but what now?

Comment: What do you understand by "Laplace's method"? Laplace had made contributions in several areas of mathematics, it is not clear which one you have in mind.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method

Comment: You are asked for the limit $x \to \infty$, right? Also, you are integrating with respect to $u$, not $t$, right? Please correct these little mistakes in order to be able to help you better.

Comment: The limit is obviously $\infty.$ Probably an error in the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laplace's method has integrals of the form

$$\int_a^b du \, f(t) e^{x g(u)} $$

be analyzed from the point of view of critical points such that $g'(u) = 0$.  In this case, this means that $u=1$.  We then Taylor expand $g(u) = g(1) + \frac12 g''(1) (u-1)^2$.  With exponential error, we may express the leading behavior of the integral as $x \to \infty$ as

$$e^{2 x} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} du \, e^{-3 x (u-1)^2} = e^{2 x} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3 x}}$$

Comment: This answer and Demoreno's answer differ by a factor of 2.

Comment: I also got this answer

Comment: @martycohen: $\operatorname{erf}(x) \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @Ron: Thanks. I was thinking of erfc.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the where the usual reasoning for Laplace's method leads us.

Let me write the integral as $\exp{(x f(u))}$, where $f(u)$ has a global maximum at $u_* = 1$. We could anticipate that the major contribution to the integral is coming from the neighbourhood of $u = u_*$ as $x \to \infty$. If we expanded the argument of the exponential about $u = u_*$ we would find:

$$ I(x) = \int^\infty_0 \mathrm{e}^{xf(u)} \, \mathrm{d}u \approx \int^\infty_0 \mathrm{e}^{x \left[ f(u_*) + \frac{1}{2}f''(u_*)(u-u_*)^2 \right] } \, \mathrm{d}u, $$ where $f(u_*) = 2$ and $f''(u_*) = -6$ (of course, $f'(u_*)=0$). Now, we call Mathematica to solve the last integral to come up with:

$$I(x) \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{12 x}} \mathrm{e}^{2 x} \left(1+\text{erf}\left( \sqrt{3x}\right)\right), \quad x \to \infty $$ where $\mathrm{erf}$ is the error function. We have obtained two terms in the asymptotic expansion of $I(x)$.

Hope this helps

---

Note that if you do not retain the second order in the expansion of $f$ you end up with a non-convergent integral for $u$ leading to the value of $I$ at $x \to \infty$, which is not precisely what we desire.

---

Here's a comparison between the numerical integration of $I(x)$ (black solid line) and the two-term asymptotic expansion (dashed line):

[image]

Comment: Is the maximum not at $u=1$ and also, I just need to work out the first term in the approximation.

Comment: You are right. I'm trying to figure out the leading order with Mathematica. I'll let you know what's going on with the integral!